# How to use progress bar message on the page using ajax for asp.net mvc application

Tags: jquery

I need to show the Please wait message while doing something on the page.

While showing this message I need to hide entire page background that is I should not give any permission to the user to do anything on the page..

Using jquery for asp.net mvc application.

Comment: And... what if I disable CSS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the jQuery UI Dialog plugin with the modal option set to true.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: And if you'd like a progressbar in the modal dialog, jQuery UI has that as well:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/